# Arduino serial communication and Python

Tags: python, arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pyserial problem with Arduino - works with the Python shell but not in a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618141/pyserial-problem-with-arduino-works-with-the-python-shell-but-not-in-a-program)

So I just got myself an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), and now I'm trying to communicate with it using [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus). I've got it working with the Serial Monitor provided by the Arduino IDE, and now I'm testing it with [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).

The program should make a LED on the board blink when it read data from the USB.

The way I do it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)
ser.write("something")
```

This doesn't work, but doing each step in the interactive shell works:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)
>>> ser.write("something")
```

I've tried using a timeout in the script before closing, but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ahh, awesome. Ive googled around for 1-2 hours, but haven't found this post, yet. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link will help you : [arduino-python](http://principialabs.com/arduino-python-4-axis-servo-control/)

--- edited ----
My apology

The concept is sending something from python script to arduino. So the arduino can interpret it as a command to turn the LED on or off.

in Python Idle

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('com7', 9600)
>>> ser.write('ON')
```

meanwhile in arduino:

```
int LedPin = 13;
char msg = ' ';

void setup(){
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while (Serial.available()>0)
  {
    msg = Serial.read();
  }

  if (msg=='ON')
  {
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);
    msg=' ';
  } 
  else if (msg=='ON')
  {
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
  }

}
```

Comment: You should include some explanation too, posting links does not do too much as an answer. It would be a fine comment though.